# Unknown column $name php and sql

Tags: php, xampp

I am working on a project where I need to insert data into a database, but I keep getting this error: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$name' in 'field list' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ramen.php:27 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ramen.php(27): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ramen.php on line 27

here is line 27:

```
$stmt-> execute(array(':content' => $_POST['content']));
```

Here is that section of code:

```
if(isset($_POST['content'])){
    $name = $_SESSION['name'];
    echo $name;
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO notes_ (Text, User) VALUES (:content, $name);';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':content' => $_POST['content']));
}
```

Comment: Why are you even mixing "styles" like this, why did you (_properly_) add `:content` as a placeholder, but then you are trying to insert the name into the query _directly_? You are _not_ getting the SQL injection protection you get from properly using prepared statements with placeholders for that value then. And as a text literal inserted into the SQL directly, this would also be missing quotes around the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your quotes from single to double. You can inject your variable into double quoted strings.

```php
if(isset($_POST['content'])){
    $name = $_SESSION['name'];
    echo $name;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO notes_ (Text, User) VALUES (:content, $name);";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':content' => $_POST['content']));
}
```

But it could be more better if

```php
if(isset($_POST['content'])){
    $name = $_SESSION['name'];
    echo $name;
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO notes_ (Text, User) VALUES (:content, :name);';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':content' => $_POST['content'], ':name' => $name));
}
```